# Building a dynamic nested routes architechure with React and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm about to start working on an app (product catalog) that renders categories (n levels deep) and all the way down to a product details view. The user can create their own categories from an external UI and save it as a user specific profile. This in turn will be loaded before rendering my app, and the categories will essentially end up as routes.

I also need to reflect the current route in a breadcrumb component.

Does anyone have experience with handling this kind of setup?
How do I build my links? How do I make sure I can render all the routes correctly, based on the customers hierarchy fetched from a backend?

A typical use case would be that the user defines a top level category, with multiple sub categories, before it ends up with a product detail view, somewhere along the lines of this:

```
const routes = [
  category: {
    subcategory: {
      subcategory: {
        product
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I should mention that I have complete control of how the object containing the route / category information should look, as this is written from scratch.

How should I handle all the static app routes like home, 404's etc., that should not be user controlled? Should I supply them as a baseobject before merging with the user routes from the backend or simply just code them in as regular routes in my app?

I've never built this kind of dynamic architecture before; hence this question.

Here's a simplified sketch of how I'm thinking it should look.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths and https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match (`<Switch>` component usage at top level routes) combo.

Like

```
    <Route path={`${match.url}/product/:id`} component={ProductPage} />
    {category.subCategories.map(s => (
     <React.Fragment key={s.urlName}>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/${s.urlName}`}>{s.name}</Link>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/${s.urlName}`} component={CategoryPage} />
     </React.Fragment>
    ))}
```

And at top

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={WillMatch} />
      <Route path="/main-category-number-one-if-you-want-or-map-it-list-from-backend" component={CategoryPage} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
```

Off course you should create urlName of subcategory yourself. Like making it short or having a blacklist of names (like subcategory named `product` that would break your app logic)

About BreadCrumbs - you can get them buy parsing `match.url` and placing at top `CategoryPage` (the one with only 1 category found in url)